# Autolaunch of Safari

Tags: safari, monterey

Safari is not my default browser.  Something is launching that browser without any window, right in front of me.  Because it's only showing up in the dock, I have no clue it's launched.  I don't know why it's happening.

Does anybody know why this might be happening?  I can't leave my computer in **Safe Mode** for a week (as was suggested elsewhere) and I don't want to start another user on this computer.

Is there a way I can be notified when it starts up?  I looked into Shortcuts but they don't have Automation like iOS.

Truly odd behaviour.  I need to fix this.  Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear for me whether `autolaunch` happens randomly during computer usage or log-in. If it's the latter then settings for items which will open automatically when you log in are located  System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login items

There are listed items which open automatically and whether they are hidden or not. So it might be good idea to check whether Safari is automatically opened in hidden state.

Comment: It is not during log in.  My machine is running all the time.  Safari opens up headless.  There is no window.  Every time I have no clue how it opened.  I need to troubleshoot this with some kind of notification.

Comment: I would guess it might be adware or malware problem.

Comment: I have never used Safari.  No extensions, nothing.  This is very odd, with no way of chasing it that I know of.